# What happens if there is a running container in an ACI already?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

So, I want to set up a schedule with a logic app in azure for starting a container every 15/30 minutes or so to check if there is anything to process.

However, I am wondering, since I can't find any controls or checks for determining if that container is already running, what will happen if that is true?

Will there be a duplicate container started, or will it just not do anything if the container is already running?

Comment: It will spin up a new container. But why do you need to start a container to check whether there is anything to process? Can't you start the container based on an actual event / trigger like a new message on a queue?

Comment: the 3rd party that This integration/software interacts with unfortunately does not support webhooks etc. So we have to ask an endpoint for any updates since it last ran.